# How to add Python Module Index to Sphinx TOC?

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, tableofcontents

I have a python project that I am attempting to document using Sphinx. I am using.

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
]
html_theme = 'alabaster'
```

I would like to have the sidebar Table Of Contents include more then just the current document. If I have my terminology correct I want the global TOC and not the local TOC. I think [fulltoc](https://sphinxcontrib-fulltoc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) should do the trick, but I cannot find out how to accomplish what I want with or without fulltoc. How can I get the global TOC?